# Sound not properly played, buzzing sound instead of recorded sound - Portaudio

Tags: c++, portaudio

I'm trying to record and play some sound with Portaudio, the objective is to create a simple voip app, so i'm trying to transfer recorded data from the first client to a second client. The problem is when it comes to play the recorded sound, i either have no sound played, of a very buzzy sound, let me explain :

here are my record and play callback functions :

```
int recordCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer, unsigned long framesPerBuffer, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                           PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData)
{
    paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;
    const SAMPLE *rptr = (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer;
    SAMPLE *wptr = &data->recordedSamples[data->frameIndex * NUM_CHANNELS];
    long framesToCalc;
    long i;
    int finished;
    unsigned long framesLeft = data->maxFrameIndex - data->frameIndex;

    (void) outputBuffer;
    (void) timeInfo;
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) userData;

    if (framesLeft < framesPerBuffer) {
        framesToCalc = framesLeft;
        finished = paComplete;
    } else {
        framesToCalc = framesPerBuffer;
        finished = paContinue;
    } if (inputBuffer == NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i<framesToCalc; i++) {
            *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;
            if (NUM_CHANNELS == 2 ) *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;
        }
    } else {
        for(i = 0; i<framesToCalc; i++) {
            *wptr++ = *rptr++;
            if( NUM_CHANNELS == 2 ) *wptr++ = *rptr++;
        }
    }
    data->frameIndex += framesToCalc;
    return finished;
}

int playCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer, unsigned long framesPerBuffer, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                           PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData )
  {
    paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;
    data->frameIndex = 1;
    SAMPLE *rptr = &data->recordedSamples[data->frameIndex * NUM_CHANNELS];
    SAMPLE *wptr = (SAMPLE*)outputBuffer;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    int finished;
    unsigned int framesLeft = data->maxFrameIndex - data->frameIndex;

    (void) inputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) timeInfo;
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) userData;

    if (framesLeft < framesPerBuffer) {
        for (i = 0; i < framesLeft; i++) {
            *wptr++ = *rptr++;
            if (NUM_CHANNELS == 2) *wptr++ = *rptr++;
        } for (; i < framesPerBuffer; i++) {
            *wptr++ = 0;
            if (NUM_CHANNELS == 2) *wptr++ = 0;
        }
        data->frameIndex += framesLeft;
        finished = paComplete;
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < framesPerBuffer; i++) {
            *wptr++ = *rptr++;
            if (NUM_CHANNELS == 2) *wptr++ = *rptr++;
        }
        data->frameIndex += framesPerBuffer;
        finished = paContinue;
    }
    return finished;
  }
```

then here are my init, record and play functions :

```
PortAudio::PortAudio()
{
    _err = paNoError;
    PaStreamParameters baseParameters = {.channelCount = 1, .sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE, .hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL};

    init();
    _inputParameters = baseParameters;
    _inputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice();
    _inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(_inputParameters.device)->defaultLowInputLatency;
    _outputParameters = baseParameters;
    _outputParameters.channelCount = 2;
    _outputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice();
    _outputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(_outputParameters.device)->defaultLowInputLatency;
}

int PortAudio::init()
{
    int i = 0;

    _data.maxFrameIndex = _totalFrames = NUM_SECONDS * SAMPLE_RATE;
    _data.frameIndex = 0;
    _numSamples = _totalFrames * NUM_CHANNELS;
    _numBytes = _numSamples * sizeof(SAMPLE);
    _data.recordedSamples = (SAMPLE *) malloc(_numBytes);
    if (_data.recordedSamples == NULL) {
        printf("Could not allocate record array.\n");
        goto Error;
    } for(i = 0; i < _numSamples; i++) _data.recordedSamples[i] = 0;
    _err = Pa_Initialize();
    if (_err != paNoError) goto Error;
    if (_inputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: No default input device.\n");
        goto Error;
    }
    return 0;

    Error:
    return quit();
}

paTestData PortAudio::record()
{
    int i = 0;

    _err = Pa_OpenStream(&_stream, &_inputParameters, NULL, SAMPLE_RATE, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, paClipOff, recordCallback, &_data);
    if (_err != paNoError) goto done;
    _err = Pa_StartStream(_stream);
    if (_err != paNoError) goto done;
    while ((_err = Pa_IsStreamActive(_stream)) == 1)
        Pa_Sleep(1000);
    if (_err < 0) goto done;
    _err = Pa_CloseStream(_stream);
    if (_err != paNoError) goto done;
    _max = 0;
    _average = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i< _numSamples; i++ ) {
        _val = _data.recordedSamples[i];
        if (_val < 0) _val = -_val;
        if (_val > _max) {
            _max = _val;
        }
        _average += _val;
    }
    _average = _average / (double)_numSamples;
    return _data;

    done:
    return _data;
}

int PortAudio::play(paTestData Audio)
{
    _data.frameIndex = 0;
    _data = Audio;
    if (_outputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: No default output device.\n");
        goto done;
    }
    _err = Pa_OpenStream(
              &_stream,
              NULL,
              &_outputParameters,
              SAMPLE_RATE,
              FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
              paClipOff,
              playCallback,
              &_data );
    if (_err != paNoError) goto done;
    if (_stream) {
        _err = Pa_StartStream(_stream);
        if (_err != paNoError ) goto done;
        while ((_err = Pa_IsStreamActive(_stream)) == 1) Pa_Sleep(100);
        if (_err < 0) goto done;
        _err = Pa_CloseStream(_stream);
        if (_err != paNoError) goto done;
    }
    return 0;

    done:
    return quit();
}
```

now what I'm doing to try to transfer the data is in my main :

```
int main(void)
{
    PortAudio *audio = new PortAudio;

    audio->init();
    paTestData data = audio->record();
    audio->play(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Once record() returned data, the frameIndex value is the same as maxFrameIndex, when running the binary this way, it's records but nothing is played. If i try to set frameIndex to any value, it will play a horrible buzzing sound, i can't seem to find what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find what's wrong, but I messed up something, ended up cutting the [example](http://files.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__record_8c_source.html) again and it worked.